# How do I display the contents of a String array in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am new to swing and am trying to write a simple program that displays the permutations of a user-defined string by having a jtextfield that the user enters the string into, then click the jbutton, then all permutations of the string are displayed in the panel as a list. I set it up and got it working with factorials by displaying the computation in a jlabel, but What swing component should I use to display a variable amount of results? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).